# Upgrading Bios in IBM x3650 Windows Server 2003 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

Will upgrading BIOS require to reinstall the operating system. We have IBM x3650 and windows server 2003 R2 operating system. In the three years we have never upgraded the BIOS. To whomsoever we have asked, they have said there are 50 50 chances that you may have to reinst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You normally wouldn't have to reinstall the operating system in the event of a successfull BIOS update. If the update fails then that's another story. My recommendation would be to perform a full backup of the server before attempting to update the BIOS.